# How to traverse through all the files from the svn checked out repository and read its properties

Tags: svn, command-line, svn-propset

We have a requirement to check out the files from SVN and traverse through all the files to print the properties of  versions & the author. Please help me on this.Am completely new to SVN , I checked out the files through commandline tool.But not able to read the properties.Please let me know if any commands available.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to run the command line `svn info -R` ?  (the `-R` option being for *recursive*)

Comment: Thanks alot @LaurentH. ..Am able to see the properties. But it's showing only the last version of the committed file.We need to read the properties of last 3 versions and copy those properties to a text file. Please let me know if there is any option.thanks again :)

Comment: Have you tried to run `svn log -l3 -v` ? It print the revision number, author, date, list of modified files and commit message for the last 3 revisions, but you can replace 3 with any number. Does it suit you ?

Comment: May be it will work. But Its asking for password to connect to the SVN repository.Since I have already checked out the repo, am assuming connecting to the repo is not required.Pls correct me if am wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong. If you need information on previous svn revisions, then you need to connect to SVN repository.

Comment: Thanks again :) It half solved the problem. It is printing the properties of only one file that has 3 versions. But we have to print all the files versions which are having 3 and less than 3. Also, please let me know if we can print the checksum of the file for the 3 versions.I need to compare them.

Comment: @Laurent H. Any help on this?